# Dynamic Flex with 3 Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I have a row of elements that I need to respond in width as they are hovered over.  There are 3 elements in the row and I am using -webkit-flex to do the initial styling of each of them.  The first element's value is set to "2" and the other two elements are set to a value of "1".

I want it to respond to hover like this:
 - mouse over element1 - nothing happens (because it is set to a -webkit-flex value of "2").
 - mouse over element2 - element1 becomes a value of "1" and element2 becomes a value of "2".
 - mouse over element3 - element1 becomes a value of "1" and element3 becomes a value of "2".

I also want it to respond after the initial element has been changed to one:
   - (element2 = value of "2") mouse over element3 - element2 = 1 and element3 = "2".
   - etc. . .

If possible, I would like to do this with CSS.  I realize that this may be a bit too dynamic for CSS to handle and my have to be handled with JS.

Thank you in advance!

Here is a simple example:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="element1">
            <!--Title-->
        </div>
        <div id="element2">
            <!--Title-->
        </div>
        <div id="element3">
            <!--Title-->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    display: -webkit-flex;
}

#wrapper div {
    height: x;
}

        /****Element Flex Rules****/
        #wrapper element1 {
            -webkit-flex: 2;
        }

        #wrapper element2 {
            -webkit-flex: 1;
        }

        #wrapper element3 {
            -webkit-flex: 1;
        }
```

Comment: This is just a bit confusing. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It sounds like you are trying to use conditional logic?

Answer (score 0):

Your question was a little confusing. I created a fiddle based on what I could derive from your explanation.

It does use jQuery, very simple jQuery, however:

When your mouse enters a div inside of container it adds a class called .wrapper-hovered. This sets the container width to 200%, and when you hover over any of its siblings, it removes the class from them, and adds it to the element you've hovered over

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wrapper div").hover(function(){
       $(this).addClass("wrapper-hovered");
        $(this).siblings("div").removeClass("wrapper-hovered")
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zuwejwqv/1/

Comment: yes sir! change the instances of div to ul or li as needed! be sure you have the parenting/child references right